# How do I read a SAML response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I am doing a POC in ASP.Net for IdP Initiated SSO.
I get logged in successfully with my AD credentials on ADFS login page.
But, on my assertion page, how can I get the SAML response and validate the the user?
I can see the response using developer tool but how can I get it using c#?

**What I have tried:**

I tried printing the values from SAMLResponse querystring parameter (I found this somewhere after googling. So not sure about how it actually works).

```
ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;

Response.Write("Is user Authenticated = " + claimsPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString());
```

**I get this as : False**

```
Response.Write("   Current Principal  = " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.ToString());
```

**I get this as : System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal**

```
string rawSamlData = Request["SAMLResponse"];
Response.Write("Raw data \n");
Response.Write(rawSamlData);

rawSamlData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(rawSamlData);
Response.Write("after url decode \n");
Response.Write(rawSamlData);

// read the base64 encoded bytes
byte[] samlData = Convert.FromBase64String(rawSamlData);
Response.Write("after base 64 \n");
Response.Write(samlData);

// read back into a UTF string
string samlAssertion = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlData);
Response.Write("saml assertion \n");
Response.Write(samlAssertion);
```

All I get is some encrypted string. How can I decode it to SAML response and authenticate the user?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turned out that ADFS was sending the Logout Response compressed.  Use the following to decompress:

```
public static Stream Decompress(this byte[] input)
{
        var output = new MemoryStream();

        using (var compressStream = new MemoryStream(input))
        using (var decompressor = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            decompressor.CopyTo(output);

        output.Position = 0;
        return output;
}
```

And then you get the XML string with the following:

```
            var decompressedStream = data.Decompress();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream);
            decodedSaml = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SAML is configured to encrypt the token, you can't read it without access to the certificates.

Otherwise, it's just Base64. There are many online sites that will decode SAML for you so you can see what it looks like.

Instead of rolling your own use a SAML clent side stack like Kentor which will do it all for you.